# SWIFT: Keep track of a score where questions have a different score

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a Quiz app were i want to keep track of my score.

BUT, The score of questions have all some different values. I would like the score to add itself to the preceding value.

This is my code so far. I'm looking forward to your answers.
Thank you!!

(I have a separate view for the Struct and the Questions)

As you see my code, if you see some things that could be improved, please let me know

(I know that i don’t know but am eager to learn)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice1Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choice2Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    
    var storyBrain = StoryBrain() 
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        updateUI()
    }

    
    @IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        storyBrain.nextStory(userChoice: sender.currentTitle!)
        
        storyBrain.ScoreUP(userChoice: sender.currentTitle!)
        
        updateUI()
    }
    
    
    func updateUI() {
            storyLabel.text = storyBrain.getStoryTitle()
        
        scoreLabel.text = String(Int(storyBrain.score))
        choice2Button.setTitle(storyBrain.getChoice2(), for: .normal)
        choice1Button.setTitle(storyBrain.getChoice1(), for: .normal)
        
        //if (choice1Button != nil) {
         //   var score = "\(storyBrain.GetScoreX1())"
         //   scoreLabel.text = score
        //} else if (choice2Button != nil) {
          //  var score = "\(storyBrain.score + storyBrain.GetScoreX2())"
            //scoreLabel.text = score
        }
    }
```

```
import Foundation

struct Story {
    let title: String
    let choice1: String
    let choice1Destination: Int
    let choice2: String
    let choice2Destination: Int
    let scoreX1: Double
    let scoreX2: Double
}
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

    struct StoryBrain {

        var score = 0
        
        var ScoreTTT = 0

        var storyNumber = 0
        
        
        let stories = [
                       
            Story( //0
                title: “Q1”,
                choice1: “XXX”, choice1Destination: 1,
                choice2: “XXX” , choice2Destination: 1,
                scoreX1: 5, scoreX2: 3
                 ),
            Story( //1
                title: “Q2”,
                choice1: “XXX”, choice1Destination: 2,
                choice2: "XXX", choice2Destination: 2,
                scoreX1: 2, scoreX2: 7
                 ),
            Story( //2
                title: “Q3”,
                choice1: "XXX", choice1Destination: 3,
                choice2: "XXX", choice2Destination: 3,
                scoreX1: 10, scoreX2: 12
                 ),
            Story( //3
                title: “Q4”,
                choice1: "XXX", choice1Destination: 4,
                choice2: "XXX", choice2Destination: 4,
                scoreX1: 10, scoreX2: -15
                 ),
            
            Story( //4
                title: “Q”5,
                choice1: "XXX", choice1Destination: 5,
                choice2: "XXX", choice2Destination: 5,
                scoreX1: 10, scoreX2: -15
                ///there is approximatively 50Q
        
                )
        ]
        
        func getProgress() -> Float { // For the progress bar
            return Float(storyNumber) / Float(stories.count)
        }
        
       
        func getStoryTitle() -> String {
            return stories[storyNumber].title
        }
        
        func getChoice1() -> String {
            return stories[storyNumber].choice1
        }
        
        func getChoice2() -> String {
            return stories[storyNumber].choice2
        }
        
        mutating func nextStory(userChoice: String) {
            
            let currentStory = stories[storyNumber]
            if userChoice == currentStory.choice1 {
                storyNumber = currentStory.choice1Destination
            } else if userChoice == currentStory.choice2 {
                storyNumber = currentStory.choice2Destination
            }
            
        }
      //TEST FUNCTION FOR SCORE
        
     
        
        func GetScoreX1() -> Double {
            return stories[storyNumber].scoreX1
        }
        
        func GetScoreX2() -> Double {
            return stories[storyNumber].scoreX2
        }
        
        mutating func ScoreUP(userChoice: String) -> Int {
            
            let currentStory = stories[storyNumber]
            if userChoice == currentStory.choice1 {
                score = Int(Double(currentStory.scoreX1))
            } else if userChoice == currentStory.choice2 {
                score =  Int(Double(currentStory.scoreX2))
                   }
            
            return score
            }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In mutating function ScoreUP make following updates for score variable

```
if userChoice == currentStory.choice1 {
            score += Int(Double(currentStory.scoreX1))
        } else if userChoice == currentStory.choice2 {
            score += Int(Double(currentStory.scoreX2))
               }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! 

I changed it and somehow, it wont add the score from the @Struct STORY. 

I can’t figure out where my code is flawed..

Would you have an idea?

Comment: @IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {
        storyBrain.ScoreUP(userChoice: sender.currentTitle!)
        
        storyBrain.nextStory(userChoice: sender.currentTitle!)
        
        updateUI()
    }